# How to start learning Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been developing .NET applications for two years and now I want to learn new technologies in that.

I have noticed many people now prefer developing applications with asp.net MVC because it is easy to maintain and is more testable.

I tried to look at it but I found the coding bit different than the normal c# coding.

Can some body please suggest the best way to start learning asp.net MVC?

Do I need to learn MVC first, then MVC2 and MVC3?

Do I have to use to use n-hibernate or linq for database connectivity? (Because I don't know any of them)

Please Suggest.

Many Thanks

Comment: Hello thanks to all of you for your reply, can some body also suggest me a book or on-line material, which has walk through to develop a sample application like http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-ASP-NET-Commerce-Professional-Experts/dp/1430210745

Comment: This should rockstart you , Learn MVC in 7 days http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think http://www.asp.net/mvc is a good start to learn ASP.NET MVC. Also, I'd recommend to buy a good book such as [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040).

You don't have to use nHibernate or linq2SQL. You can use whatever ORM or data access technology you like best.

Also you don't need to learn MVC 1/2 first. Start directly with the current version.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to learn MVC first, then MVC2 and MVC3?

Its not necessary to learn the previous versions, you can just jump into MVC3.  It is helpful to understand the MVC pattern first, though.

This is a pretty good writeup of the history to date: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2011/06/29/The-history-of-ASP-NET-MVC-so-far.aspx

> Do I have to use to use n-hibernate...

No, using MVC doesn't force you into any ORM or data access strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're  reasonably familiar with ASP.NET MVC and start looking for more detail or recommended reading, you might find [webdev.simple-talk.com](http://webdev.simple-talk.com) useful.

*(disclosure - it's a free resource I'm working on to help people learn ASP.NET MVC)*

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Microsoft ASP.Net MVC website](http://www.asp.net/mvc). It has TONS of great tutorials, code examples, and walk throughs that cover almost all of the major aspects of ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add unit tests to any project; it does not have to be an ASP.NET MVC project to do so.
2. MVC is not right for every application. I suggest you evaluate the requirements of your application and verify that MVC is right for it.
3. I won't say it's the *best* way necessarily, but you might want to have a look at Microsoft's [ASP.NET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
4. There is no pre-requisite that you use any specific ORM for your data access layer.